# To Fetch The Names Of Workers Who Earn The Highest Salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, max(SALARY) from Worker
```

When i executed this it shows the following error:

> Column `Worker.FIRST_NAME` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not post the table schema nor the database engine you are using, so I just can guess a possible solution.
As you asked for the Names (plural) of workers who earn the highest salary you probably expect more than one result row.
So a possible solution might be the following

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, SALARY
FROM Worker
WHERE SALARY = (SELECT max(SALARY) 
                FROM Worker)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answering your question :

> To Fetch The Names Of Workers Who Earn The Highest Salary

You can use `rank()` :

```
SELECT w.First_Name, w.Salary 
FROM (SELECT w.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as Seq
      FROM worker w
     ) w
WHERE seq = 1;
```

By this way, you will get name of workers who has earned highest salary.